# Contradiction of Unique Factorization Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

In $\mathbb{Z}_6[X],$ factor each into two polynomials of degree 1:
$g(X) = X + 2,$ $h(X) = X + 3$

$$g(X) = (3x+8)(2x+1)$$

$$h(X) = (6x+1)(x+3)$$

Does this contradict the unique factorization theorem? Why or why not?

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not a field, and from our notes in class we defined the UFT to be: Each polynomial of degree at least one over a field F can be written as an element of F times a product of monic irreducible polynomials over F.
Thus, can I conclude this does contradict the UFT since $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ can be factored into monic irreducible polynomials but $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not a field? Any help in how to think about this question more clearly is helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: No $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$ is not a field. It is not an integral domain, since $2\cdot 3=0$.

Comment: Hey, what's this? You asked the same question yesterday or before yesterday! Where is the previous version?

Comment: @Bernard: The OP knows this, read carefully.

Comment: To the OP: Are you playing games with us? When you posted this question, your username was "Liz3"; now it's "Clover3". You have asked the same question recently, and you have received the same answer as today. Aren't you going to say anything?

Comment: I posted an edited version.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contradict the UFT because the theorem says "over a field" and, as you observe, $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not a field. So "no prob."